# Can LD_PRELOAD be used to load different versions of glibc?

Tags: c, ld, glibc, ld-preload

### Cast of characters

- `big-old-app` is linked to an old version of `glibc`, say `glibc-2.12`.  I cannot do anything to change this.
- `cute-new-addon.o` is linked to a newer version, `glibc-2.23`.  This `glibc-2.23` is in a nonstandard path (because I don't have sudo powers).

### The story

I want to use `cute-new-addon.o` inside `big-old-app`.  I would normally write a script for `big-old-app` to execute, which then calls `cute-new-addon.o` to perform its tricks. From the command line, it would look like:

```
$ big-old-app script.txt
```

However, when I do that, `big-old-app` would complain that `cute-new-addon.o` cannot find `glibc-2.23`.  That's understandable, because I have not specified any standard paths.  What if I do:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/mylibs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH big-old-app script.txt
```

It segfaults! :(

I think this is because `big-old-app` references a newer `mylibc.so.6`.  When doing so, the implementations are no longer what `big-old-app` is used to, so it segfaults.

### The question

Regarding `script.txt`, I don't think I have the ability to specify the newer `mylibc.so.6` before invoking `cute-new-addon.o`.  `big-old-app` and `cute-new-addon.o` are tightly intertwined that I have no way of knowing when either of them need their corresponding `glibc`.

And yes, `cute-new-addon.o` `rpath` is pointed to `/path/to/mylibs` and I can confirm via `ldd` that all the libraries it needs, it looks for in `/path/to/mylibs`.

Can I use `LD_PRELOAD` to load two different versions of `glibc`? And let `big-old-app` and `cute-new-addon.o` look for what they need as they please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617 has explanation of why `LD_PRELOAD` doesn't work, and possible workarounds.

Answer (score 4):

`LD_PRELOAD` cannot be used because the glibc dynamic linker (sometimes called `ld.so` or the program interpreter; the location on disk is platform-specific) is only compatible with `libc.so.6` (and the rest of the libraries) from the same glibc build.

You can use an explicit loader invocation of the other glibc, along with library path settings that cause the loader to load the glibc objects from a separate directory, and not the system directories.  The [glibc wiki](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds#Compile_normally.2C_run_under_new_glibc) has an example how to do this.

Comment: **Building glibc without installing** : "... The prefix `/usr` is considered the correct prefix for a system glibc." I have a feeling this is necessary to "load the glibc objects from a separate directory". Am I on the right track?

Comment: No, you can build with `--prefix=/usr` and still keep the copy in a separate location, perhaps by installing it using `make install DESTDIR=/path/to/alternative/tree`.