# Using a different libc (32) when executing a binary on a 64 bit machine (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: ubuntu, libc, ld-preload, ubuntu-20.04, ctf

I am trying to execute a 32bit binary and use a custom libc with it. So, I used `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable to set the path.

```sh
export LD_PRELOAD='./libc.so.6'
```

After this, a simple `ls` shows this error -

```sh
ERROR: ld.so: object './libc.so.6' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
```

I am currently trying this on a Ubuntu 20.04 64bit machine and I receive this error. This technique used to work fine on the same machine with Ubuntu 18.04. Why is this happening and is there a workaround for this?

Context: I am trying a CTF challenge and using `LD_PRELOAD` is a common technique used when the challenge also provides a custom `libc`. I tried running scripts that use this approach and used to work fine on Ubuntu 18.04 but they throw the same error.

Edit:
The `ls` command works fine but also prints the error message. Any command executed will work correctly and also show this error. Major issue is that why doesn't this work on Ubuntu 20.04 whereas it worked perfectly on 18.

Comment: When you set `LD_PRELOAD` with `export`, it applies to all programs you try to run, including all your regular 64-bit system programs like `ls`.  So that seems like it clearly won't work.  Does it work if you just set the variable on the command line when you run your specific program, e.g. `LD_PRELOAD='./libc.so.6' ./myprog`?

Comment: It still crashes with a `Segmentation Fault`

Comment: Okay, maybe your program still crashes, but at least `ls` works again, right?  (I assume that you have `unset LD_PRELOAD` or started a new shell?)

Comment: I am sorry if the question was confusing. By `ls` shows the error I meant that any command executed after setting the variable, printed this error and worked correctly. My issue is that I have used this before and it works fine but it crashes for some reason on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host) Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55186770/can-ld-preload-be-used-to-load-different-versions-of-glibc

Comment: Yes. I found a fix using `patchelf` but I still want to understand why `LD_PRELOAD` fails.