# Modify Relocations Conditionally at Runtime

Tags: linker, elf, glibc, ld-preload, relocation

**TL;DR**

I want to **overwrite** `.got, .got.plt,...` to point to the **correct** addresses, because the linker makes **wrong** decisions.

---

I need to use two different *dynamic allocation* functions (i.e., `malloc(),...`) in the code. The appropriate one will be selected based on some condition during program execution. Therefore, I provided two `glibc` instances and used the `LD_PRELOAD` trick. The `LD_PRELOAD` value is something like the following:

```
LD_PRELOAD=multiplexer_library.so:glibc1.so:glibc2.so
```

where, `multiplexer_library.so` chooses the correct library. `glibc1.so` is accessed using `dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc")` and `glibc2.so` is accessed using `dlopen()` followed by `dlsym()`. The same goes for `calloc(),...`

The problem is that the second malloc will **interfere** with the first one. This happens because **all** dynamic relocations of the **latter** will be **mapped** to the **former** by the linker. For example, when `glibc2.so` calls the global function pointer `morecore` it will be mapped to the `morecore` and its target which is the `__default_morecore()` function in `glibc1.so`. The relocation entry for this global variable in `glibc2.so` is as follows:

```
0000003addc0  085600000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT 00000000003af4d8 __morecore@@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
```

I traced the execution in `Pin`. **125** out of over **1370** relocation entries, were **accessed** in my code during dynamic allocations. For example, an **imporant** entry is the global variable `__curbrk` which determines the `brk` boundary for dynamic allocations (NOTE THAT I provided an **isolated** brk region for **each** library at the system call level). This will obviously **corrupt** the allocations, because both allocators use the same `__curbrk`. The relocation entry for `__curbrk` in `glibc1.so` is shown below:

```
0000003adeb8  044400000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT 00000000003b10b8 __curbrk@@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
```

I tried to **rename** these conflicting names but **125** is a **huge** number and the code is **hard** to grasp. Because it is full of **nested macros** which makes the manual rename solution, practically, **infeasible**.

IIUC, for **each** relocation entry, there exists **a memory address** (e.g., somewhere in `.got,...`) where the **linker** will put the **target** relocated address and this address is **exclusive** to **each** shared library. I will call that address the **TARGET HOLDER**. For example, in the `__curbrk` case, the linker placed the *runtime* address for the `__curbrk` variable of `glibc1.so` in the **target holder** of `__curbrk` in **both** `glibc1.so` and `glibc2.so`. If this is right, at **runtime**, I will have to **update** the value in the **target holder** of `__curbrk` in `glibc2.so` to hold the **runtime** address of `__curbrk` variable of `glibc2.so`. And to **completely** resolve the problem, this should be done for **all** of the **125** relocation entries **accessed** by `malloc(),...`. Is it possible?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Instead of modifing glibc, you should modify your program so that it call user-defined functions for memory-allocation.

Comment: The programs are **not** modifiable. They are *realworld* applications, such as `evince` and `wireshark`. You are saying that I should **extract** the allocation code from `glibc` and **use** it in my code? Unfortunately, knowing the exact **boundaries** for the `glibc` **allocator** implementation is **hard**. This seems to be **harder** than **renaming** the *relocatable symbols*.

Comment: You could try and explain what is the _actual problem_ you wish to solve (cf XY-problem).

Comment: The program **crashes** using the above-mentioned `LD_PRELOAD`-based approach. The **main** reason seems to be that the **two** shared libraries are using the **same** global variables. For example, `__curbrk` has the **same** *address* and, **consequently**, *value*, in **both** libraries, **while** two, completely **isolated**, memory regions for dynamic allocation chunks is needed. This is because the linker **maps**  **all** relocations (i.e., relocations in **both** libraries) to the **first** library.

Comment: _two, completely isolated, memory regions for dynamic allocation chunks is needed_ Why?

Comment: The reason is out of the scope of this question, but it is needed. Briefly, the reason is that I will need to the dynamic data allocated by **each** shared library should be placed in **separate** `128KB` **contiguous physical memory** regions. For example, virtual addresses in the range `[0KB-128KB[` will be managed by the first library, the range `[128KB-256KB[` will be managed by the second library, `[256KB-384KB[` by the first library,...

Comment: I didn't want to delve into `glibc` *dynamic allocator* because of its **complexity** and to **enhance portability** I decided to use two **separate** `glibc` libraries and use each of them for a *dedicated* region. The region is **isolated** in each library.

Answer (score 3):

> Therefore, I provided two glibc instances and used the LD_PRELOAD trick.

[These](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55186835/50617) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) explain why using `LD_PRELOAD=glibc.so` can not work (at least not reliably).

> I decided to use two separate glibc libraries and use each of them for a dedicated region. The region is isolated in each library.

This can't possibly work, because designers of GLIBC don't support this approach. You'll need to do something *else*.

Comment: Thanks for the *great* information. I do **not** want the whole `glibc` in the second `glibc2.so`. I only want **whatever** is called by the *dynamic allocation functions* (e.g., `malloc(),...`), directly/indirectly. I **hook** these entry functions using `LD_PRELOAD`.... I **also** called the internal `ptmalloc_init()` function which is typically called by the linker for **initialization**. But the **relocations** seem to **fail**. As the executed code is **limited**, do you see any **other** reason for the failure?